# Return Column headers based on cell values associated with Row Header

Tags: vba, function, excel, worksheet-function

This is the set up I have at the moment.

Sheet1:

Rows A2:A5 I have listed:

```
Dog 1
Dog 2
Dog 3
Dog 4
```

Columns B1:E1 I have listed

```
Black
White
Brown
Grey
```

For examples sake, in the first row I have listed (from B2:E2):
REQUIRED, REQUIRED, IDENTIFIER, IDENTIFIER

On Sheet2, set up is as follows:

Cell A1 has a drop down list of dog 1-4

Cell B1 has "required"

Cell C1 has "identifier"

Goal:
My goal is, whatever dog I pick from the drop down list on sheet2, I would like the formula to scan sheet1!A2:A5, find the dog and then scan the horizontal row associated with that dog, recognize the "required" and "identifiers" and extract the column headers and organize them under the Required & Identified on sheet2.

Example:

I pick dog 1 from my drop down list (on sheet2), it will lookup sheet1!A2:A5 then recognize dog 1 is located on A2, then lookup horizontally recognize "required" and "identifier" in cells B2:E2, then it will extract column headers "black" and "white" and input those headers under its appropraite field ("required" - cell B1) ("identifier" - cell C1) in sheet2.

I would highly appreciate your help on this. The solution can be either VBA or formulas. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In your example Dog 1 has required in Black and White. How would that show on your resulting Sheet2.B1? Ie "Black, White"?

Comment: @nbayly yes, I would like black and white listed under Sheet2!B1 (which has the column header "Required")

Comment: I'm having difficulty figuring out a way to smartly concatenate my results. I can get them into an array but after I can't join all the outputs together. Sadly concatenate doesn't work on arrays. Is it always going to have just the 4 types of descriptors (black, white, brown and grey)? I can make a less flexible solution if that's the case.

Comment: @nbayly unfortunately it will not be as simple as those 4. In my document that contains the real data, I have 101 unique column headers.

Comment: @nbayly Is it possible to reference the column headers once the formula recognizes "required" or "identifier"? For example! when the formula recognizes Sheet1!B2 as "required", sheet1!B1 will automatically go to sheet2!B2 under the "required column". I can attach a sample worksheet later on today to get a better visualization. Thank you for looking into this though

Comment: Yes you can do that. The problem is that you have to do that numerous times on each formula as more than 1 cell matches that. But then you can't put the answers together because of limitations with Excel's native `CONCATENATE` function. I have found a solution that combines a formula with a custom VBA UDF that I found. Info in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by placing "Data Validation" on your `A1` cell on Sheet 2 and restrict the list to `A2:A5`, or you can select the whole `A:A` range and select the "Ignore Blanks" option. This will allow you to choose the value of `A1` by a dropdown with the appropriate dogs.

Then on `B1` you would place the following array formula:

```
=StringConcat(", ",IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A2:A5,0)+1)&":E"&(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A2:A5,0)+1))="REQUIRED",Sheet1!$B$1:$E$1,""))
```

Note that this is inputted by pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`. You would replicate this for `C1` except change "REQUIRED" to "IDENTIFIER".

The `StringConcat` is a custom UDF made by Chip Pearson that you can find here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx. Copy the code he offers into a VBA module and you're off to the races.

Comment: You can change the amount of columns from Sheet 1 by changing the references to column `E` to extend to the last column you need to consider.